# Intellij concordion not finding file after test

Tags: intellij-idea, linux-mint, concordion

I'm trying to visualize the output of a test of concordion but I cannot open the html file.
I'm using linux mint, and maybe is something related to permission in the temp file? but I don't know how to fix it.

Using Linux Mint, intelliJ IDEA community, installed concordion(v3.1.2) library from maven,simple sum [a,b] and test.

[Cannot open the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26Xa8.png)

[Tried on browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6OHp.png)

Comment: You should be able to right click on the file link in IntelliJ and select "Open in <browser>" where <browser> is whatever browser you are using. You could also try pasting the link into the browser URL bar and see if you can open it. 
Which browser are you using? 
Have you tried any other browsers?

Comment: I used google chrome and firefox, the "Tried on browser" link shows an image of that.

Comment: From a terminal window, can you run `ls -al /tmp/concordion/dummy/spec` and see what it lists? The only thing I can think at the moment is that `/tmp` is emptied out after a reboot

Comment: You can change the location of the output specification using a system property, see https://concordion.org/coding/java/markdown/#concordion-output-location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out that maybe the problem is the installation of the IntelliJ IDEA from the linux mint software. Therefore, I unsinstalled and reainstalled from the official web, and now the test html is showing correctly!